# symbol loopkup error: libgobject-2.0.so.0:undefined symbol: g_bytes_unref

Tags: c, qt, gstreamer, rtsp

I am trying to compile a gstreamer rtsp server under ubuntu 12.10 using Qt creator.

The code successfully compiled but give me this exception and the program exit:

> symbol loopkup error: libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_bytes_unref

Here is my .pro file ( linked all the needed libs )

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = gstreamer
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-0.10

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /home/kato/ew-gst-sdk-linux-x86_64-2012.03-0/include/gstreamer-0.10
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/glib-2.0
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/libxml2

LIBS += -L/home/kato/ew-gst-sdk-linux-x86_64-2012.03-0/lib \
-lgstreamer-0.10 \
-lgstrtsp-0.10 \
-lgstrtspserver-0.10 \
-lgobject-2.0 \
-lglib-2.0 \
-lgio-2.0 \
-lgthread-2.0 \
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of glib is installed?  `GBytes` is relatively new, only since [2.32](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Byte-Arrays.html#g-bytes-ref)

Comment: I am using glib-2.0, but when I am using command ldd to know the required libs, It tells me that glib-2.0 is required, I will try install glib-2.32.